# OpenCV Video Capturing API

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV in MSVC++ for creating a Video Capturing API using webcam. But I want that flash light of webcam should be off at the time of capturing of videos and images. I guess there should be an issue related to hardware or registry files. Any solutions for this...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't control the flash light of your webcam with OpenCV.
If you don't want the light on while recording, the easiest thing to do is probably put something in front of it.